# Kotlin: Convert a map's key set into a String Array

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set the options of a Spinner's drop-down menu, which requires taking in an Array of options as the last parameter. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

> java.util.HashMap$KeySet cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Below is my code:

```
var ringtoneNamesToURIs: MutableMap<String, String> = getRingtoneList()
var ringtoneNames: Array<String> = ringtoneNamesToURIs.keys as Array<String>

val ringtoneSpinner = root.findViewById(R.id.ringtoneSpinner) as Spinner
val ringtoneDropdown: ArrayAdapter<String>? = context?.let {
    ArrayAdapter<String>(
        it,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        ringtoneNames
    )
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a List rather than an Array. It's more Kotlinic and also works with Android's ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in a map are saved in a Set, not in an array. So you can not just cast.
You have to covert the keys set to an array.

```
val ringtoneNames:Array<String> = ringtoneNamesToURIs.keys.toTypedArray()
```